# Find the number of occurrences in an array using another array?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Let's say there is a base:

```
CREATE TABLE test (
    ids integer[]
);
```

With data

```
INSERT INTO test VALUES ('{1, 2, 3, 4}');
INSERT INTO test VALUES ('{5}');
```

I would like to find the number of occurrences of an arbitrary array, say: '{5,1}' in the test database, in what way can this be done?

In my attempts, I could only find the total number of elements in the array, except for those found:

```
select sum(array_length(array(
    (select unnest(ids) except select unnest(array[5,1]))
), 1)) from test;
```

But, i need exactly the number of occurrences found from the transferred array. How i can find . that?

[DbFiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/m512he4QazSkD2cBmkEWr/0)

Comment: If one row contained both 1 and 5, should that be counted once or twice?

Comment: @jjanes Only once. For example, in the example that's in the post, the answer should be: 2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You possibly want this:

```
select count(*) from test, unnest(ids) as id where id =ANY('{5,1}');
```

Or to count each row from test at most once, then this:

```
select count(*) from test where ids && '{5,1}'
```

They both give '2' in your example, but they don't do the same thing in general.